# Rails: Cucumber + Capybara - How to add http method in visit ()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, cucumber, capybara

I have this step definition:

```
Given /^I am not logged in$/ do
  visit '/users/sign_out'
end
```

And **rake routes** gives me this:

```
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
```

So.. How would I test this? Is there any way I can add the HTTP method in Capybara?

I say this because I keep getting this error in my tests:

```
 No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out" (ActionController::RoutingError)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change:

```
config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

for

```
config.sign_out_via = Rails.env.test? ? :get : :delete
```

in `config/initializers/devise.rb`

As explained in [Rails-Devise-Rspec-Cucumber tutorial](http://railsapps.github.com/tutorial-rails-devise-rspec-cucumber.html), by doing so, you are going to make Devise to do GET requests for sign out actions. And this is just going to happen in test environments...

Comment: Linked document seems to be behind a paywall now

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going on here.

1. You have a step that is defining state, but the implementation is performing an action. I'd expect that step to assert that you aren't logged in, something like:

   ```
   current_path.should eq(home_url)
   ```
2. The `visit` method will only issue GET requests. `RackTest` will simulate delete requests if you give it a link, so to perform the `sign_out` action you would want to simulate it with the browser:

   ```
   within('nav') { click_on('Logout') }
   ```

   Alternatively you can mix in `Rack::Test::Methods` and then use `delete` directly:

   ```
   World(Rack::Test::Methods)

   Given /^I am not logged in$/ do
     delete '/users/sign_out'
   end
   ```

You have a tradeoff between correctness, as in the way a user would really log out, and speed, in not loading the page at all. You'll have to choose which way is right in the context of your scenario and how often you'll be using the step.

Comment: Hi pselbert. I would like to do the click on logout, but the problem is that if the user is not sign in, I am not even showing the sign out link, and therefore I can't do the sign out.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [Nobita's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10065851/158028), if you're overriding Devise's default routes then you'll need to edit `routes.rb` as well:

```
as :user do
  # Sample custom routes
  get '/register' => 'devise/registrations#new', as: :new_user_registration
  post '/register' => 'devise/registrations#create', as: :user_registration
  get '/login' => 'devise/sessions#new', as: :new_user_session
  post '/login' => 'devise/sessions#create', as: :user_session
  get '/my-account' => 'devise/registrations#edit', as: :edit_user_registration
  # This tells the test environment that GETting the logout path is OK
  if Rails.env.test?
    get '/logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session
  else
    delete '/logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`RAILS_ENV=test rails assets:precompile` helped in my case